# How can I show how to make code block in Markdown within a code block?

Tags: commonmark

I tried this:

````
```text
```bash
```
```
````

but in CommonMark (see http://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%60%60%60text%0A%60%60%60bash%0A%60%60%60%0A%60%60%60) it doesn't work.

### What I want

````
<pre><code data-sourcepos="1:1-3:7" class="language-text">```bash
```
</code></pre>
````

### What I get

````
<pre><code data-sourcepos="1:1-3:7" class="language-text">```bash
</code></pre>
<pre><code data-sourcepos="4:1-4:3"></code></pre>
````

Comment: @Jongware I'm not sure what you mean. I've just tried to clarifiy it. Did it become clear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply create an outer code block with more backticks than the inner one:

`````
````text
```bash
```
````
`````

[commonmark.js dingus](http://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%60%60%60%60text%0A%60%60%60bash%0A%60%60%60%0A%60%60%60%60)

From the [CommonMark spec](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.25/#fenced-code-blocks):

> A code fence is a sequence of **at least three** consecutive backtick characters (`) or tildes (~). (Tildes and backticks cannot be mixed.) A fenced code block begins with a code fence, indented no more than three spaces.
>
> [...]
>
> The content of the code block consists of all subsequent lines, until a closing code fence of the same type as the code block began with (backticks or tildes), and with **at least as many** backticks or tildes as the opening code fence.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Interesting! Could you please add the first part of the specs: http://spec.commonmark.org/0.25/#fenced-code-blocks and highlight the "at least"?